# AS3 enemy formations

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I have been developing a shooter game in as3 using the starling framework by looking at some different tutorials. 
The problem is that all tutorials teach to create random enemies that move from one side to other. I want to know how can I create different formations of enemies on screen.

Can anyone suggest any books, tutorials, or any basic algorithm to put me on track?

Comment: When you want to learn a language you have to start by reading the official documentation. It's often boring and far from what you want to achieve but if you base your knowledge upon tutorials you won't be able to diverge from them and do stuff by yourself. Check the doc on Starling's website and Thibault Imbert's book.

Comment: An enemy formation is just that, a sequence of enemies that get spawned at predefined (relative) positions. So, in order to make one, you need a data structure holding in-game time, enemy type, coordinates of its spawn, maybe something else, and fill it as you wish. When you process everything in one game loop (a single enterframe listener will do), query the time against that structure, and if there's a match, spawn enemies.

Comment: Vesper's basically got about as good of an answer as you can really get for this sort of thing.  This is the sort of thing that you should mostly try to think of yourself.  If you try to mimic somebody else's style, even if you tweak it, you'll still be held back pretty badly.  You have to take very vague, general best practices, and then go from there to create stuff conjured up on your own.  These best practices themselves would just be like "use good OOP" and "look out for race conditions".  Other things can be fairly cookie-cutter, but not quite so much something this creative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rather simple way to spawn a formation.

Create a symbol in your library called `formation` and use that as your linkage/class name as well.

In that symbol place 5 marker MovieClips at whatever locations you want. For the marker clip I recommend using a circle that is centered. Wherever you place those markers, represents where the enemies will be spawned.

Now, in your code where you want to spawn this formation, you can do this :

```
var formationData:MovieClip = new formation;
for (var index:int = 0;index < formationData.numChildren;index++)
{
    var spawnMarker:MovieClip = formationData.getChildAt(index) as MovieClip;
    var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy;
    enemy.x = spawnMarker.x;
    enemy.y = spawnMarker.y;
    addChild(enemy);
}
```

Now, that will spawn a formation based on what you set up in your formation symbol.

You can offset the location of your enemies that get spawned by doing something like this :

```
var offsetX:Number = 200;
var offsetY:Number = 50;
for (var index:int = 0;index < formationData.numChildren;index++)
{
    var spawnMarker:MovieClip = formationData.getChildAt(index) as MovieClip;
    var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy;
    enemy.x = offsetX + spawnMarker.x;
    enemy.y = offsetY + spawnMarker.y;
    addChild(enemy);
}
```

What this concept allows you to do, is visually layout your formations in the flash IDE. So you could create a whole bunch of different formations and choose a random one. Have the spawn points spell out a word ?

Obviously the code above is an example, you would need to integrate the concept into your spawn system etc.

Depending on where your enemies are spawning from, you might need to use the offset to start them offscreen.